# Logging in while asking a question

Tags: bug, status-norepro, login

At the bottom, under the question input, there used to be a magic box where you typed basically anything into it and it would log you in.

However that's now gone, and the new one is not better at all. It's just a *Log In* button. Which if you click, loses your question you've just spent ages typing.

It is extremely simple what needs to go there. A miniature version of the login page, with all the same buttons.

Or at least the previous text box, with a short explanation saying that you can just type your email address or URL (like gmail.com).

Please fix this, you have no idea how frustrating it is to lose the question you've just typed. And it's more frustrating when a feature is changed to something worse.

Comment: Hint: Always make a back-up before posting huge amount of text. No matter which web page.

Comment: Ok I was over exaggerating on the spending ages bit. But it's annoying and it was fine before it changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not lose your question when you log in.

At least, we can't reproduce that -- in fact, we do track the question and post it when you log in.

Comment: Well I pressed log in, and it took me to the place where you choose the provider, then clicked Google logo, typed in my Google details on the google page, it came back and the text wasn't in the box and my answer wasn't submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I typed this answer while logged out, and just clicked the "log in" link.

It in turn ensured the answer was filled, however I still needed to click "Post Your Answer" after I logged in (by-design).